# compare / contrast Jesus' baptism with John's

Tags: john, jesus, baptism

Jesus' baptism with the Spirit is compared/ contrasted on purpose by John. What is his purpose in doing so?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Both John and Jesus were baptised in water - do you have a specific text to examine?

Comment: What text are you focusing on, please ? This is a very broad subject and we need to focus on a specific text. Please have a look at the Tour and the Help to see that this site focuses specifically on the text of scripture and is not a forum for general discussion of biblical topics.

Comment: luke 3:16;Acts 1:5; 11:16

Comment: You need to [edit] the question to add and ideally quote those verses. Even so, I can't see how this wouldn't be too opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Since John's purpose was to introduce Christ, John's baptism prepared the way for Christ. John baptized with water to repentance, to change of heart; for death to self and life to God. John wasn't the light. Jesus is the light and the truth. He's God. Jesus' baptism, in the Spirit (in God) or in the fire, is the reality of baptism. Which He did on Pentecost, and then at Cornelius' house, to His believers, once He'd become a life-giving Spirit. John spoke this directly, the Lord Jesus repeated the thought in John 3 to Nicodemus.